# Point cakephp 3 model to a different table

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-3.0

For database organisation purposes, I have added pretext for every table.
I would then name models in Cakephp without the pretext, for less writing when calling them.

In Cakephp 2 I would use `public $useTable = 'dev_pictures';` to point "Picture" model to "dev_pictures" table, in Cakephp 3, this has no effect. How would i do it in Cakephp 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Why not simply reading the migration guide?](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html)

It's now [Table::table()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_table), the method is a getter and setter. Set the table name in your tables initialize() method.

Comment: `Table::table()` and the deprecation of `$useTable` aren't mentioned in (the current version of) the migration guide.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 3.0 doesn't support table_prefix and 3.1 doesn't seem to be addressing that. So, in the meantime I think the simplest solution is doing the following:

```
class Picture extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'dev_pictures';

}
```

(Take in account that CakePHP 2.x prefix support was not really solid).